# insert text between two logos on title page (horizontally)

Tags: graphics, header-footer, titles, logos

I need to insert two logos of my university between its name like this
[image: header]

But the best I made is this
[image: my header]

Logos are slightly different but it doesn't matter. I was trying to put images into the `figure` environment, tried the `wrapfig` package, but none of them worked. So is there any way to put images as they should be?

```tex
{\small \sc \bf
      \includegraphics[width=1.3cm, height=1.3cm]{msu-logo.png}
      MOSCOW GOVERNMENT UNIVERSITY
      \includegraphics[width=1.3cm, height=1.3cm]{cmc-logo2.png}\\
      named after M.V.~Lomonosov\\
      The faculty of Computational Mathematics and Cybernetics
      \par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.1pt}
}
```

Comment: please see if the answer meets the requirement -- the font size can be changed to fit the lines between the logos on both sides

Comment: @jsbibra, thanks, the only thing is that text should be centered, but I think I'll be able to do so. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\long\def\mytitle{%
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}%
                \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
            \end{minipage}\hspace{10pt}
            \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}%
                  MOSCOW GOVERNMENT UNIVERSITY\\
                  named after M.V.~Lomonosov\\
                  The faculty of Computational Mathematics and Cybernetics\\
            \end{minipage}\hspace{10pt}
        \begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}%
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{tikzpicture}%
            \draw[thick, brown] (0,0)--(0.99\textwidth,0);%   
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
}


\begin{document}
    \mytitle
\end{document}
```